# Query about connections to oracle by tnsnames

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, tnsnames

I am newbie to oracle connections. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me why before I was able to connect to oracle by cmd using:

```
c:\chris> sqlplus
c:\chris> Enter user name : system
c:\chris> Enter password:
```

However now I can't connect using system, instead I must use system@orcl

```
c:\chris> sqlplus
c:\chris> Enter user name : system@ORCL
c:\chris> Enter password:
```

My tnsnames is:

[TNSNAMES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOrhP.png)

PD: Thank you.

Comment: Did you change your env variables? if you do not specify a tnsnames alias, sqlplus takes ORACLE_SID and tries to connect to it. If it is empty, then it will not be able to connect. What error do you get?

Comment: @gsalem Hi. I get "TNS:protocol adapter error". My environment variable has as 
Name: TNS_ADMIN and as value: ORCL

Comment: TNS_ADMIN should have as value the directory where the tnsnames.ora file is located, not the SID of the database instance.

Comment: @gsalem Yes. The TNS_ADMIN environment variable points to the tnsnames.ora file. I think I am missing to declare the variable ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME
But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: as I said, TNS_ADMIN should point to the directory containing the file and not the file itself. ORACLE_HOME should be specified also.